# BULK INSERT WITH INDEX INPLSQL

Tags: plsql, bulkinsert

Table contains id mobile and CNIC COLUMN .NEED TO INSERT 1000 RECORDS WITH BULK INSERT. The records insert randomly. I.e mobile and cnic randomly generated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The example below creates 10 rows with random data. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_RANDOM.html) for `DBMS_RANDOM` for other formats (lower case, mixed case, numeric, etc)

```
create table some_random_data (mobile VARCHAR2(10),cnic VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO some_random_data (mobile, cnic)
  SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING(opt => 'u', len => 10), DBMS_RANDOM.STRING(opt => 'u', len => 10)
   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
   
select * from some_random_data;

MOBILE     CNIC      
---------- ----------
KCAHKDLFTS IFCPMVWKXF
PHBKAIYILO CNHZCPMETJ
XLMQEFVGCP CYYGCKLZQW
RNSBSKUOTG FTVKWUMXRC
YAHKVEYTZS MESMLPWHFY
LAZYAYTLDT NJZXHNSRUR
DHSMSQIRSB TXXRBYYAVY
XLCYPTRKDF GZOYLDQIQS
ZMIAKOHYXC LQCXQSAKXV
WPRHZEBNZR QYMEZIAKXN

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: can you do this with procedure and bulk inserting using forall loop

Comment: ```FORALL``` statement is used to loop through a collection. There is no collection mentioned in your question. Can do a normal ```FOR LOOP``` to loop from 1 to 1000. Check the other comments - your question is extremely vague it's very hard to understand what it is you're trying to achieve